# OneLogin does not pass back SAML RelayState

Tags: saml, onelogin

In SAML, if the SP sends a RelayState parameter during an SP-initiated SSO login, the IdP (OneLogin) should send the RelayState back exactly as the SP sent it. This can be used to navigate to a particular page, etc.

However, OneLogin doesn't seem to be sending it back. When configuring a OneLogin app, the configuration has a field called RelayState. I've never needed it before now so I've left that empty thinking it's is the 'default' RelayState in case the SP doesn't send one or in case its a IdP initiated login but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a way to get OneLogin to send back the RelayState the SP sent during an SP-initiated login? Do I need to add some variable/tag in this RelayState app configuration field? As an aside, even if I put something random in the RelayState field OneLogin is not getting sent to the SP even on an IdP initiated login (so maybe I need to turn it on somewhere I'm not seeing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested here using our SP application and OneLogin without any issues. The relay state included with the SAML authn request was returned by OneLogin with the SAML response.

My understanding is that the relay state that can be configured in OneLogin is for IdP-initiated SSO only. I've left this blank. There was no special setting required in OneLogin to get it to correctly return the relay state as part of SP-initiated SSO.

Are you sending the authn request using HTTP-Redirect or HTTP-Post?

Either should work. I suggest double checking the RelayState parameter is included correctly with the authn request.

Comment: Site note: According to the SAML spec, in SP-initiated SSO flow the IdP must replay the value of the RelayState without changing it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm an idiot. I was using the wrong method to get query parameters and didn't catch it in the Chrome plugin until I just tried again (for the 20th time). Your answer helped a lot and made me recheck my assumptions.